# Spark: Measure performance of UDF on large dataset

Tags: performance, apache-spark

I want to measure performance of an udf on a large dataset. The spark SQL is:

```
spark.sql("SELECT my_udf(value) as results FROM my_table")
```

The udf returns an array. The issue I'm facing is how to make this execute without returning the data to the driver. I need an action but anything returning the full data set will crash the driver, eg. collect or I'm not running the calculation for all rows (show/take(n)). So how can i trigger the calculation and not return all data to the driver?

Comment: in your actual business process, you gotta be doing something with this udf - like agrgregating or joining. 

you should probably include that in the performance measurement.

measuring a "collect" doesnt make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the closest you can get to only running your UDF for measuring timing would be something like below.  The general idea is using caching to try and remove data loading time from your measurement, and then use a `foreach` that does nothing to make spark run your UDF.

```scala
val myFunc: String => Int = _.length
val myUdf = udf(myFunc)

val data = Seq("a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa")
val df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF("text")

// Cache to remove data loading from measurements as much as possible
// Also, do a foreach no-op action to force the data to load and cache before our test
df.cache()
df.foreach(row => {})

// Run the test, grabbing before and after time
val start = System.nanoTime()
val udfDf = df.withColumn("udf_column", myUdf($"text"))

// Force spark to run your UDF and do nothing with the result so we don't include any writing time in our measurement
udfDf.rdd.foreach(row => {})

// Get the total elapsed time
val elapsedNs = System.nanoTime() - start
```